# Selenium scrolling randomly

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I am trying to scrape data from a table from several hundred pages on a website. Here is part of what I have so far:

```
driver.get("link")
driver.maximize_window()
window_before = driver.window_handles[0]
driver.switch_to.window(window_before)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 350)")
games = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="schedule"]/tbody/tr')
```

This code only works sometimes. If I run this chunk 10 times, only 5 times will the website actually scroll down. I tried using this:

```
for i in range(0, 2): driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="meta"]/div[1]/p[1]/a').send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
```

but the same issue arises. Sometimes that scrolls down the amount I need, other times it does nothing, and other times it scrolls the entire page.

This part of my code navigates to the first link I need to click and on the next page I need to scroll another page, where the same issue is present. This is all part of a loop that goes through several hundred pages to read html tables, so even if it works the first 50 times, I won't get all the data I need.

Edit: Directly after the above snippet I have this:

```
for idx, game in enumerate(games):

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div[6]/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr['+str(idx+1)+']/td[6]/a').click()
```

Which is where I get the "element is not clickable at point (X, Y)" error.

Am I doing something wrong here, or is there a work around to accomplish my goal?

Comment: Why do you need to scroll at all?

Comment: @MattDMo The link won't be interactable if it's not in view, hence I need to navigate further down the page.

Comment: Are you clicking on it manually or using Selenium?

Comment: Of course, it would also help if you would confirm the url of the page you are trying to scrape, as well as your end goal: what are you after from those pages, and in what format?

Comment: @MattDMo Clicking on it using Selenium.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus What do you mean confirm the url? If the driver opens the correct webpage, then the url should be correct, or no? My end goal is to scrape an html table using read_html into a DataFrame. I haven't included that part of my code because this issue happens before it gets that far. On the occasion all the "scrolling lines" work correctly, the tables are scraped correctly.

Comment: Mate, give us the url, so we can test this issue. It could be that said element is only loading on scroll, in which case the proper way of doing it is to isolate a static element (not loaded via XHR, or generated by JS) and scroll that into view, allowing the dynamic ones to load as well, then trying to locate them. Also: are you testing that page, or are you trying to scrape the information from it?

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus "https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2014_games-october.html" I'm not trying to scrape information from this page, just navigate to the links "Box Score" below.

Comment: @sla813 I edited my answer - let me know if that's what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to access `href` attribute for every 'Box Score' link from that page (according to OP's clarification in comments):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,720")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
actions = ActionChains(browser)
url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2014_games-october.html'
browser.get(url)

# print(browser.page_source)
# browser.maximize_window()
try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="qc-cmp2-summary-section"]'))).click()
    print('clicked cookie parent')
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@mode="primary"]'))).click()
    print('accepted cookies')
except Exception as e:
    print('no cookies')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="all_schedule"]'))).location_once_scrolled_into_view
table_with_score_links = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//table[@id="schedule"]')))
# print(table_with_score_links.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
links_from_table = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in table_with_score_links.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'a') if x.text == 'Box Score']
print(links_from_table)
```

Result printed in terminal:

```
clicked cookie parent
accepted cookies
['https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201310290IND.html', 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201310290MIA.html', 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201310290LAL.html', 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201310300CLE.html', 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201310300TOR.html', 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201310300PHI.html', 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201310300DET.html', 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201310300NYK.html', 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201310300NOP.html', 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201310300MIN.html', 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201310300HOU.html', 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201310300SAS.html', 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201310300DAL.html', 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201310300UTA.html', 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201310300PHO.html', 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201310300SAC.html', 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201310300GSW.html', 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201310310CHI.html', 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201310310LAC.html']
```

I tried to make variable names as descriptive as possible, and also left some commented out lines of code, to help with the thought process - build up to reach the end goal.

You can now go through those links one by one, etc.

Selenium documentation can be found here: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/

Comment: I have everything imported. If the browser doesn't scroll down a wait will not help because even if the wait is for 1 million seconds, the element will never be in view. Also, click() does not bring the element into view. If the browser does not scroll down, then I get an error saying that the element is not clickable at point (X, Y).

Comment: Can you confirm the url, @sla813?

Comment: This isn't exactly what I was going for, but using what you have here led me to doing what I needed to do in a better way. Instead of scrolling and clicking on each link, I now just use .get() to navigate to the links retrieved.